# What's a good way to display Important Notice headings on a blog?

Tags: website-design, alerts, bootstrap, blog

I have a blog/content website that has notices on the landing page, done using Bootstrap.

A notice is a piece of time-critical information that expires (almost, but not quite, an alert). There won't be more than 2-3 notices at any given time. Clicking on a notice heading on the home page leads to another screen that has more information about that notice. My current design is something like this:

[image: The notices titles are the blue banners]

What can I do to make the notices stand out better, without being too "in your face" and detracting from the blog posts below? Should they be moved elsewhere on the page?

Comment: Make it yellow.

Comment: Sometime instead of using bold color we can use some animations with bold move or notification sound which will catch user attention.

Comment: What @Tot Zam said.

Answer (score 3):

[Bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) come with four color options. Each color represents how much attention a user should give the notice.

[image: alert colors]

`alert-info` (Blue) - information that is helpful, yet not necessary to read
`alert-warning` (Yellow) - important information that you really should read
`alert-danger` (Red) - crucial information that you must read

Blue is considered a peaceful and safe color. By making the alert blue, you are basically indicating that the alert is helpful, yet is also safe to ignore.

Yellow is a warning color. You are letting the user know that something can go wrong if they skip this notice. If you want users to pay more attention to the alert, change the color to yellow.

Really important notices can be set to red, yet this should not be used often since red is usually an indication that something is really wrong.